# Cannot install dependencies on React project using typescript - conflict problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

Any dependency that I try to install in project, I get a typescript conflict problem.
I've tried to resolve it updating dependencies, downgrading it, removing node_modules and package-lock.json to reinstall, but nothing solves it.

Step to reproduce:

```
npm install axios
```

Error description:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peer typescript@"*" from eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@34.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@"^34.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   2 more (tsutils, the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.55.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.55.0",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^34.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

What I've already done to try to fix it::
Update typescrip(Initial version was 5.0.1):

```
npm install typescript@5.2.2
```

Remove node_modules and package-lock.json:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Clean npm cache:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Here some information from GitHub ( https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080)

try to add this in your package.json :

```
"overrides": {
  "typescript": "^5.0.3",
},
```